# Unable to execute Jest esm tests with amcharts5 lib

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to migrate the execution of Jest unit tests in ESM isolated mode.
Execution goes well (and much faster than in normal mode), but using the @amcharts/amcharts graph library execution fails.

```
FAIL  src/app/app.component.router.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Must use import to load ES Module: /vif/tmp/jest-preset-angular-main/examples/example-app-v15/node_modules/d3-shape/src/index.js

      at Runtime.requireModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:841:21)
```

I tried to add transformIgnorePattern in jest config file but it's the same.

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!d3-|@amcharts|tslib)`]
```

It's possible to reproduce in https://github.com/tidou44/jest-preset-angular /examples/example-app-v15
I just add @amcharts/amcharts5 dependency and use it in app.component.ts

when i run npm run test-esm-isolated , i have the error

Does anyone knows what is wrong ?

Thank you in advance

It's possible to reproduce in https://github.com/tidou44/jest-preset-angular /examples/example-app-v15 I just add @amcharts/amcharts5 dependency and use it in app.component.ts

when i run npm run test-esm-isolated , i have the error

Does anyone knows what is wrong ?